# This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: element "tags": string required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to add the type but its not picking it up I am confused how to give the `boot_disk` and 'network_interface' type if I created the type as object.
Error : `│ This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: element "tags": string required.`

```
variable worker {
    type        = map(string)
    default     = {
        worker_count = 2
        name         = "k3s-master"
        machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
        tags         = ["k3s", "k3s-master"]
        zone         = "us-central1-a"


        boot_disk = {
            initialize_params = {
            image = "debian-9-stretch-v20200805"
            }
        }

        network_interface = {
            network = "default"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you currently set your variable is to expect a map of strings and you are providing a list of strings for tags. What you could try is to set the variable type to `map(any)`.

Comment: Can you share your variable definition and how it then gets used by a resource? Ideally your Terraform code should take the form of a [mcve] so people can run it and see the specific error you are getting or at least see how it all fits together.

Comment: It's not a Google Cloud question. I removed the tags. In addition @MarkoE comment is the terraform answer!!

Comment: Not quite correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@MarkoE's answer in the comment is close, but not quite correct. Terraform's `map` type is a "collection", and per [Terraform's documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html), "all elements of a collection must always be of the same type."

Since your variable has different types for different fields (e.g. `worker_count` is a `number`, but `tags` is a `list(string)`), `map(any)` will not work.

Since it looks like you want to strictly type the variable, what you probably want is the `object` type. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
variable "worker" {
    type = object({
      worker_count = number
      name         = string
      machine_type = string
      tags         = list(string)
      zone         = string
      boot_disk    = object({
        initialize_params = object({
          image = string
        })
      })
      network_interface = object({
        network = string
      })
    })

    default = ...
}
```

Comment: Yup, thanks for expanding, your answer is indeed the correct way to do it. :)